# How to limit rows in each group to a specific number in My SQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have two MySQL Tables. **user_tbl** storing details of users and **feedback_tbl** stores feedback about them. Following is the Table Structure.

**user_tbl**

---

user_id

user_name

user_pic

mgr_id

business_unit

**feedback_tbl**

---

feedback_id

emp_id

feedback (varchar)

rating

date_info (datetime)

---

Note : **emp_id** in feedback_tbl is foreign key mapping to **user_id** in user_tbl

The result I need to have is take **latest feedback of 3 users in each business_unit field.**
I have used query,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, u.user_pic,    u.business_unit, f.feedback, f.rating,f.date_info 
FROM user_tbl AS u , feedback_tbl AS f 
WHERE u.user_id = f.emp_id ORDER BY f.date_info DESC) AS t 
GROUP BY t.business_unit, t.user_id
```

to get latest feedback of users in each **business_unit**. But this query gives me more rows of data for each **business_unit** as I'm having more than 10 users. 
So How can limit 3 user feedback  for each 
business_unit ? Any Help?

Comment: add `limit 3` at the end of the query.

Comment: It wont work @PrerakSola.  I need 3 rows each for each business_unit. Not just 3 rows as result.

Comment: Then add it in the inner select query.